# gulpの自動圧縮を実行しないようにしたい。

Tags: gulp

gulpを使っているのですが、100kbを超えると、すべてのjsファイルの自動的圧縮がはじまり、5時間くらい終わりません。
下記のようなメッセージがコマンドプロンプトに出てきます。

```
～.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB"
```

ページ表記時に実行するjsファイルであれば、何時間待っても圧縮したほうがいいですが、
クリック時に実行するので、圧縮したからと言って、ページ表記速度が上がるわけではないので。
メリットを感じません。
これはデフォルトの挙動のようですが、止めるないしは、行わないようにすることはできないのでしょうか？

下記のように変更したところ問題解決しました。

```
   gulp.task('babel', function() {
      gulp.src('./babel/*.js', ['babel'])
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(babel({
          presets: ['es2015'],
          compact: false,    // ←この行を追加
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    });
```

Comment: そのメッセージを出しているのはgulp自身ではなく、gulpによって実行された処理の1つだと思います（恐らくbabelです）。　実際にどのような処理が走っているのか確かめるために、`gulpfile.js`の内容を追記していただけないでしょうか。（質問文を編集して追記できます。）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

その処理はbabelによって行なわれています。自動圧縮を行わないようにするには、[babelのcompactオプション](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#compact)を`false`に設定します。
具体的には、`gulp-babel`を使用している以下の部分に書き加えます。

```
gulp.task('babeltrance', function() {
  gulp.src('./babel-before/*.js', ['babeltrance'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015'],
      compact: false,    // ←この行を追加
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

---

また、この設定では、処理を走らせるたびに全ファイルが処理の対象となっています。[gulp-changed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed)（または[gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer)等）を用いることで、前回から変更があったファイルのみを対象に処理させることで無駄な処理の時間を減らせます。あわせてご検討ください。

Comment: うまくいきました。ありがとうございました。